# How can I make data sortable by date in an SQL populated table?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, sql, html-table

Currently I have a page that displays ALL ORDERS on the system on a single page, this part is working fine and is not a problem. The issue occurs when we reach a certain amount of orders I want to make it easy to digest, so the max orders that will show on a page at once will be 15 and the data will be sortable for faster searching.

My code is below:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "qwe";
    $password = "qwe";
    $dbname = "qwe";

    // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Orders ORDER BY ID DESC";                         
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        echo "<table class='table table-hover' id='orders'><tr style='font-size:18px;'><th style='text-align:center;'>ID</th><th style='text-align:center;'>Customer</th><th style='text-align:center;'>Material</th><th style='text-align:center;'>Quantity</th><th style='text-align:center;'>Delivery</th><th style='text-align:center;'>Post Code</th><th style='text-align:center;'>Cost / Tonne</th><th style='text-align:center;'>Total</th><th style='text-align:center;'>Paid</th><th style='text-align:center;'>Staff</th><th style='text-align:center;'>Timestamp</th></tr>";
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
            echo "<tr style='font-size:16px; text-align:center;'><td><span style='color:#0b78e5;'>SGL</span><a href='#' style='color:#0b78e5;'>".$row["ID"]."</a></td><td>".$row["Customername"]."</td><td>".$row["Material"]."</td><td>".$row["Quantity"]."</td><td><input type='checkbox' disabled". ($row["Delivery"] == 'Yes' ? " checked" : "")  ."></td><td>".$row["Postcode"]."</td><td>&pound;".$row["CostPerTonne"]."</td><td>&pound;".$row["TotalCost"]."</td><td>".$row["Paid"]."</td><td>".$row["Username"]."</td><td>".$row["Logged"]."</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "There are 0 orders in the system";
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

My question is using the data I already have is there any way of making the table sortable by date?

Comment: Looks like you need pagination. Search for the same at Stack overflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sort by date , you have to create a column with timestamp data type and keep the default value as current_timestamp , or guessing the orders with larger id is latest , you current code will be sorted by date. you can use datatables https://www.datatables.net/ , data tables provide sorting in reverse order by all columns and a search for making your search for an item easier